# Why feature selection using `L1` and not using `L2` norm?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, lasso, ridge-regression

I read a tutorial [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/regularization-in-machine-learning-connecting-the-dots-c6e030bfaddd). In which, I came across the below plots

[image]

I read an explanation quoted `Fig 8(a) shows the area of L1 and L2 Norms together. For same amount of Bias term generated, the area occupied by L1 Norm is small. But L1 Norm doesn’t concede any space close to the axes. This is what causes the point of intersection between the L1 Norm and Gradient Descent Contour to converge near the axes leading to feature selection.`

From the above graphs and explanation, I can understand the below

a) Area occupied by `L1` norm is small when compared to `L2` norm

But I didn't understand what the author means as `But L1 Norm doesn’t concede any space close to the axes.` and how this leads to feature selection?

can help me understand this, please?

Comment: One answer in the duplicate thread uses the same image.  For more about this see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=lasso.

Comment: The quote is considering l1 and l2 [balls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)#In_normed_vector_spaces) of equal radius. It says that the l1 ball has less total volume. But, if we restrict our attention to the vicinity of the axes, both balls occupy similar volume in this sub-region. So, if you spread out the same amount of mass uniformly over each ball then, in the l1 ball, the mass would be concentrated closer to the axes.

Comment: hi @user20160 - Is there anyway you can explain this visually? Sorry, if I am asking you for too much help. Unfortunately, am not from a CS background but trying to learn ML

Comment: I think I didn't understand this `So, if you spread out the same amount of mass uniformly over each ball then, in the l1 ball, the mass would be concentrated closer to the axes`... What I inferred from the vicinity of axes is that both L1 and L2 ball have 4 points (in 4 quadrants) in the same position.

Comment: Regarding the 'vicinity of the axes' comment...In the figure you posted, imagine painting red lines over the axes (with a little bit of width to them, but not too much). Count the number of pixels in the image that fall within the l2 ball and also overlap with the red lines. Do the same for the l1 ball. The two numbers should be similar. Regarding the 'concentration' comment, imagine spreading 1 million points uniformly over the surface of each ball. Measure the distance of each point to the axes. The average distance will be less for the l1 ball, compared to the l2 ball.

Answer (score 1):

It means when we near to axis for an optimization (minimization or maximization) task, we will have a narrower and sharp neighborhood to reach to the optimal point in Norm 1, in contrast to Norm 2.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate in simple terms, please? I am not from CS background.  Based on what (in the plot), do they say that L1 Norm doesn’t concede any space close to the axes? upvoted btw

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. May I know how to do they assess/find out that L1 norm doesn't concede space close to the axes?